# 17.5 hour overnight layover in Zurich

Tags: layovers, accommodation, sleeping, zurich, zrh

I'm looking at ordering a flight which has a a 17:30 hours overnight layover in Zurich. I will be arriving at the airport at 19:30 and my departure flight is the following day at 12:45.

I have two main questions

1. Is there any way to see the city given these time constraints?
2. I'm looking for a place to sleep after exploring the city that's either close to the train station or at the airport. Mainly looking for something cheap and clean. Are there any recommendations?

Comment: @pnuts I don't need a visa to get into the Schengen Zone. The requirements for the hotel are that it's clean, has a shower and would not take too long to commute to the airport from. I edited the question to have this info. Thanks for the tip!